# Postgres in WSL: PANIC: could not flush dirty data

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, postgresql

### Problem and Solution attempts

1. I'm getting the following error: `PANIC:  could not flush dirty data: Function not implemented` - It's a reported issue with WSL
2. I'm working in development. Production isn't a consideration right now.
3. I'm trying to run postgres in WSL (fresh install of windows, wsl, and postgres as of this morning)
4. I've tried turning `fsync = off` and `data-sync-retry = true` - Neither worked.

### What I need

I just need to be able to start postgres for development.

Comment: What steps do I need to follow to reproduce your situation?

Comment: It's a bug with WSL + postgres, so you'd have to be running WSL and try and start postgres, which I imagine is like so for everyone: `sudo service postgresql start` (@Biswapriyo)

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing a few months ago (run postres on WSL), and got this error as a WARN when creating a database - you could ignore it and it seemed to work fine regardless. Now it seems to be a PANIC, so I can't even start postgres. I've just decided not to run dev databases on WSL anymore - WSL is basically the world's biggest hack, and stuff like this is bound to keep happening. In my opinion WSL is great for basic command line stuff (like SSH to linux boxes - finally no more putty) but as things stand it's just not stable and robust enough for running entire dev envs

Comment: @davidpostill deleted my answer post (did it because it's easier to see at a glance than a comment). I stopped using postgres in WSL and just installed and ran it via Windows.